# Single view application has a black background which cannot be changed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `objective-c` to develop a single view app which is targeted for 11.4 `iOS`, and the `Xcode` version is 9.4.1.

After creation, there are Main.storyboard and LaunchScreen.storyboard, I changed the background for Main.storyboard to yellow.

Then load `rootViewController` with blow codesnip:

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
```

When I run the app, the app's background is black instead of yellow, what is wrong?

========================
add screenshot:
[image]

========================
add code for init rootviewcontroller:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen alloc] bounds]];

    self.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

=======================
I can confirm it is that code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions failed, all work fine if I comment out those code in the method, don't know why.

Comment: check if background alpha is set to 0 or color to clear from somewhere else

Comment: please provide storyboard id in you initialier

Comment: add Main.Storyboard id as "ViewController" and using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController", and the alpha is set to 1, still not work, my emulator is iPhone7

Comment: is this possible to attach your project

Comment: Can you please show us your `storyboard`?

Comment: @iPeter how to attach?

Comment: Take a screenshot of your `storyboard` and attach the image by `ctrl+g`.

Comment: @iPeter screenshot attached

Comment: no need to write any codes anywhere. Just run the project and make sure your main interface is set to **Main** in your project settings.

Comment: @iPeter yes, I created a new app without and code, just drag and drop a label, now the background is white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the cause, the

```
initWithFrame:[[UIScreen alloc] bounds]
```

should be

```
initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your do not need to fire any code to get your `Main.storyboard` initial view controller.

Delete the code and go to `Project settings -> General tab` here you will find `Main Interface` see if it is set to `Main`(your storyboard name)

[image]

Also check your in you `storyboard` that the entry point is set to your desired `viewcontroller` or not.

[image]

Run your project and see.

Comment: got an exception "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch" after delete code for set root view controller

Comment: @JamesHao check your `main.m` file for this code ```int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}```

Comment: @JamesHao also check wheather the `View` in you `View Controller` is connected to the `reference outlet` of your `ViewController`'s `view` property

Comment: the main.m is untouched, if I create a new app without adding any code, the background will be white, however, if I add some code, the background will be black, don't know where I broke the logic.

Comment: the view is referenced by default,

Comment: Hmm need to check this, I will let you know once I find it out

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get your view controller on start up,

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewController Storyboard ID."];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a “Main.storyboard” already added in the project.
Select its ViewController , go to property inspector . tick the “initial view controller” option.
Create View controller in the “Main.storyboard” say LoginVC , give it the Class and Storyboard ID

Create rootviewcontroller in app delegate.enter image description here
[image]

[image]

```css
let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as UIViewController
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: change as you mentioned, now the launch screen is yellow, however, immediately it turned to black. don't know why

Comment: Please send your code where you are setting the rootviewcontroller.

Comment: I have one storyboard "Main.storyboard" . I set "Main.storyboard" as Launch screen file in General settings of project. Then i go to "Main.storyboard" , set it as initial view controller from Property inspector. And initiated my view controller in app delegate.

Comment: let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as UIViewController
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()